# C# Inconsistant Accessibility on public method (with ref)

Tags: c#

I searched some fora and topics to look for the answer but I'm not able to find the solution for my problem. I'll post the code:

```
namespace Configurator
{
    public partial class Dialog : Form
    {
        private DataStorage dataStorage = null;

        public Dialog
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void setDataStorage(ref DataStorage ds)
        {
            this.dataStorage = ds;
        }
    }
}
```

> And it's being used in this class:

```
namespace Configurator
{
    public partial class MainView : Form
    {
        private DataStorage dataStorage = new DataStorage();
        private Dialog DialogBox = new Dialog();

        public MainView
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void newObjectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogBox.Show();
            DialogBox.setDataStorage(ref dataStorage);
        }
    }
}
```

> This is the error:
>   **Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'ref Configurator.DataStorage' is less accessible than method Configurator.Dialog.setDataStorage(ref Configurator.DataStorage)**

Comment: and the error was ? I'm guessing your 'DataStorage' has to be public. We don't have the code for that

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that! One minute!

Comment: Make dataStorage variable as public

Comment: The `accessibility` tag you used is meant for question about helping people with disabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark your class `DataStorage` with `public` and your error will go away :)

Your class `Dialog` is public. Your method `setDataStorage` is also public. This makes this method visible to all other assemblies. But how can other assemblies use that method if they do not have access to the parameter type `DataStorage` because that one is not visible (probably because it is marked private or internal.)

Comment: @ Martin Mulder & @ Codelgnoto Unfortunately, it didn't do the trick. Still have the same error. Thanks for trying!

Comment: Are you missing the word public after DataStorage?  So the class matches the method in which it is used - Mark your class DataStorage **public**...

Comment: @David: Wow, is missed the most important thing in my answer. Thanks!

Comment: YP28: Sorry, my answer was not complete. Try again! :)

Comment: My DataStorage class has no access identifiers. I marked it as public now, the first error is gone, but some others popped up. Fixing those is the only thing left for me now then (: Thanks David and Martin. All the others too of course!

Comment: Vote Up requires 15 reputation... -.-" Sorry Martin!

Comment: @YP28: No appologies needed, my answer lacked the most important thing, the keyword `public`. I hope it will work for you now :)

Comment: It does (: only had to modify the other classes to public too, those were the remaining errors.

Comment: I do not think the word SOLVED is needed. It is creative though. The sysem will only recognize the green tick. :)